# Interpreting the output of summary(glmer(...)) in R

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I'm an R noob, I hope you can help me:

I'm trying to analyse a dataset in R, but I'm not sure how to interpret the output of `summary(glmer(...))` and the documentation isn't a big help:

```
> data_chosen_stim<-glmer(open_chosen_stim~closed_chosen_stim+day+(1|ID),family=binomial,data=chosenMovement)
> summary(data_chosen_stim)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: open_chosen_stim ~ closed_chosen_stim + day + (1 | ID)
   Data: chosenMovement

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    96.7    105.5    -44.4     88.7       62 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4062 -1.0749  0.7111  0.8787  1.0223 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 66, groups: ID, 35

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)           0.4511     0.8715   0.518    0.605
closed_chosen_stim2   0.4783     0.5047   0.948    0.343
day                  -0.2476     0.5060  -0.489    0.625

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) cls__2
clsd_chsn_2 -0.347       
day         -0.916  0.077
```

I understand the GLM behind it, but I can't see the weights of the independent variables and their error bounds.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "weights", exactly. There's a section there summarizing the fixed effects, with coefficient estimates and standard errors. Is there something else you're looking for?

Comment: If p(y|x, w, s²) = exp((yw^Tx - A(w^T x))/s² + c(y,s²)), then I'm looking for p(w|y,x) essentially. Is that the `Estimate`, etc in the fixed effects section?

Comment: Uh.....paging @BenBolker!

Comment: @zombiecalypse I don't follow your notation, but the `Estimate` column are the \beta_i for the model constant term (intercept) and the two terms in your model. If this were a (G)LM (no random effects) these would be the model coefficients; the things you wanted to estimate the effect on the response of.

Comment: I have to say I don't follow your notation either ... this may be more appropriate for CrossValidated (where you can also use LaTeX notation in your question and it will be nicely rendered)

Comment: A couple more comments. (1) Are you also asking for standard errors on the working weights themselves?  I don't know offhand how these would be calculated -- can you point me at a reference? (If you're asking for something else, please clarify) (2) Your title/introductory sentence say "I don't understand the summary", but your question is rather more specific.  I'd recommend editing accordingly and, if you have other specific questions about the summary, asking a new question.  ("I don't understand the summary, please explain" would be a little too broad to be a good question ...)

Answer (score 0):

**update**: `weights.merMod` already has a `type` argument ...

I *think* what you're looking for `weights(object,type="working")`.

I believe these are the diagonal elements of `W` in your notation?

Here's a trivial example that matches up the results of `glm` and `glmer` (since the random effect is bogus and gets an estimated variance of zero, the fixed effects, weights, etc etc converges to the same value).

Note that the `weights()` accessor returns the *prior* weights by default (these are all equal to 1 for the example below).

Example (from `?glm`):

```
 d.AD <- data.frame(treatment=gl(3,3),
                    outcome=gl(3,1,9),
                    counts=c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12))
 glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson(),
                data=d.AD)
 library(lme4)
 d.AD$f <- 1  ## dummy grouping variable
 glmer.D93 <- glmer(counts ~ outcome + treatment + (1|f),
                    family = poisson(),
                    data=d.AD,
                    control=glmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1="ignore"))
```

Fixed effects and weights are the same:

```
 all.equal(fixef(glmer.D93),coef(glm.D93))  ## TRUE
 all.equal(unname(weights(glm.D93,type="working")),
                  weights(glmer.D93,type="working"),
           tol=1e-7)   ## TRUE
```